# How to get list of bitmaps saved in custom adapter to the main activity?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a gallery of images. Those Images are being fetched from an online database. I have the bitmap for each of the images.

Upon Pressing on one of them, it will zoom in to display the image needed.

However, if you click (or swipe) the currently zoomed in image , the next image will be displayed and so on until you reach the max elements that are in my image gallery gridview (perhaps i can check it by doing  final int size = gv.getChildCount(); ).

The problem is the following : the list containing the all of the bitmaps is in my GalleryCustomAdapter and where I need it is in a fragment Gallery_Restaurant and I don't know how I can access the list in the GalleryCustomAdapter from the Gallery_Restaurant fragment.

The list I need to access from the fragment is :

```
public List<Bitmap> pics;
```

I wrote a getter for it

```
 public List<Bitmap> getPics()
    {
        return pics;
    }
```

I attached part of the code:

1-GalleryCustomAdapter

```
public class GalleryCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private final Context context;
    public View cv;

    public List<Bitmap> pics;


    private List<GalleryComposedObject> lstItems;

    public GalleryCustomAdapter(Context context, List<GalleryComposedObject> lstItems)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.lstItems = lstItems;
    }


    public List<Bitmap> getPics()
    {
        return pics;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount () {
        return lstItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId (int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem (int position) {
        return lstItems.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        GalleryCustomAdapter.RowHoder holder = null;
        if(convertView == null)
        {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.gallery_layout_instance, parent, false);
            cv= convertView;
            holder = new GalleryCustomAdapter.RowHoder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gallery_image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (GalleryCustomAdapter.RowHoder) convertView.getTag();


        new DownloadImageTask(holder.imgIcon).execute(lstItems.get(position).getIconsUri());
      // holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(lstItems.get(position).getIconsUri());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class RowHoder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;

    }



    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {


            pics.add(result);

            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }


}
```

2- Gallery_Restaurant fragment

```
public class Gallery_Restaurant extends Fragment {


    private ArrayList<GalleryComposedObject> lstData;
    GridView GalleryGridview;

    private List<Bitmap> zoomimgs;
    View v;
    long currid;


    public Gallery_Restaurant() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_layout, container, false);

        String _id = getArguments().getString("restid");

        Log.d("this","n" + _id);

        //String _id = getActivity().get_id();

        String method = "getrestpic";
        BackgroundServerTask backgroundtask  = new BackgroundServerTask(view.getContext(),view);
        backgroundtask.execute(method, _id  ,"restaurant");


        /*GalleryGridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.GalleryGridview);
        lstData = new ArrayList<GalleryComposedObject>() ;
        int i;
        for (i=0; i< iconsUri.length; i++) {
            lstData.add(new GalleryComposedObject(iconsUri[i]));
        }
        GalleryCustomAdapter customAdapter = new GalleryCustomAdapter(view.getContext(), lstData);

        GalleryGridview.setAdapter(customAdapter);*/

        v=view;

        final GridView gv = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.GalleryGridview);
        final ImageView Zoom = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagezoom);

        Zoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               /* gv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/


               //lenght of the gridview
               // final int size = gv.getChildCount();

                //GalleryCustomAdapter.RowHoder holder = (GalleryCustomAdapter.RowHoder) view.getTag();

            }
        });





        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                GalleryCustomAdapter.RowHoder holder = (GalleryCustomAdapter.RowHoder) view.getTag();

                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)holder.imgIcon.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                Zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Zoom.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                gv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                currid=id;

                CustomViewPager ViewPagerObj = (CustomViewPager)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
                ViewPagerObj.setSwipeable(false);
            }
        });

        return view;

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting null pointer exception? Because I didn't find 'pics' initialization.in your adapter.

Comment: no null refrences

Comment: Bek you were right i got a null refrence

Comment: Any success? Or any questions?

Comment: yes , it worked thank you for you too Bek. However, I am facing problems in the next step now

Comment: What's problem?

Comment: the size of the list is too big , there should be 5 elements but there is 9 instead

Comment: Sorry for late response. Explain what you want briefly. Why are you using two adapters?

Comment: i need to first get pictures from an online database (where url are stored) then second download these pictures given their urls and putting them in a gridview and finally upon pressing on one of them i will get a slider with the item clicked viewed first and when you swipe you see other pictures

Comment: Indeed, your implementation is wrong. Try to make like this. First make a call to get pictures path, then pass list of pictures path to your gridviewadapter (change it accordingly). in gridviewadapters getview show pictures using picasso or glide. on picture click open a new activity download specific image pathes, then pass images to gallerycustomadapter.  In gallerycustomadapters getview show pictures using picasso  or glide. don't downlaod or don't make asynctask call on getview it freezes your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your adapter as parameter in your fragment:

```
private GalleryCustomAdapter customAdapter;
```

Then create a public getter in your adapter so you can get all your bitmaps.
Like your `getPics()`

Then when you need to picture on click:

```
Bitmap bitmap = customAdapter.getPics()
```

Comment: the customAdapter in question is created in the background task class in onpostexecute ... how do i get it from there into the fragment?

Comment: and the background task is inner class? if so there is not a problem.

Comment: it is not an inner class, it does background tasks for multiple purposes

Comment: So create the adapter as parameter in your Background Task. Then create a public getter for that adapter. and in your fragment when you click, use your backgroundtask.getYourAdapter()

Comment: thank you it seems like it worked , however , i am getting an error of null reference as Bek mentioned earlier that I didn't saw earlier , it is saying :

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.user.letsdine.GalleryCustomAdapter$DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(GalleryCustomAdapter.java:118)

Comment: points to pics.add(result)   result is the result of downloadimage which is a bitmap

Comment: Its sounds like you not initialized your list at the begining. List<Bitmap> pics = new ArrayList();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160379/discussion-between-motis10-and-sara-kat).